# Create two large text areas encompassing the entire screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have two gigantic text areas that encompass the entire screen. I tried adjusting the number of rows and columns and this did not work also I would prefer to have it responsive to the screen. I am open to using bootstrap but I also want to keep this as simple as possible.

Here is t[he project](http://ven-diagram.herokuapp.com/) and the relevant code:

```
    Enter two text blocks to compare:
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <textarea name="A"></textarea>
        <textarea name="B"> </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>
```

Here is the entire document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ven Diagram</title>
<style type=”text/css”>
form{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

textarea:first-child{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}

textarea:nth-child(2){
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    This program allows you to match text.

    Enter two text blocks to compare:
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <textarea name="A"></textarea>
        <textarea name="B"> </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            Results:
            <pre>
                {% for message in messages %}
{{ message }}
                {% endfor %}
            </pre>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</body>
```

~

Comment: Have you tried anything? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you have provided, I think this the thing you want.

Just go to the link and `resize` the browser.

It will work for the all size of screens. Click on `Edit this pen` at lower left corner of the screen to see the code.

http://codepen.io/neonirav/full/dbtmk

Regards.

Comment: For some reason I had to add cols too.

Comment: I didn't quite get you... Can you explain more

Comment: cols define the fixed width. That is absolute amount of width. By giving relative width you can change it with screen resolution. As applied in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rows/cols that bootstrap provide don't cover the entire width. Try this

```
form{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

textarea:first-child{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}

textarea:nth-child(2){
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: thx for help. I posted the whole file. Can you see why its not working?